# Eviews vs R (Statistical Software)

Tags: r, time-series, econometrics, software, eviews

Are there many features in Eviews that R misses? I have heard that especially when dealing with time series R is less extensive than Eviews. Is this true? Which of the two packages contains most statistical tools (or are they comparable?)?

Comment: Comparing the R packages in the [time series](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html) & [econometrics](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Econometrics.html) task views to the Eviews [feature list](http://www.eviews.com/EViews8/ev8features.html) should help you. Note that R describes itself as a language & environment for statistical computing & graphics - if you know an algorithm you want to implement, & someone hasn't already done so; you can, building on functions & data types already available.

Comment: I have never heard of Eviews.

Comment: Eviews is a statistic package. Less familiar than R but used by many academics.